# How to implement isWeekday() and isWeekend()?

Tags: java, calendar

I would like to ask. 
I've a date format like 2011-06-05 00:00:00
I want to construct a method in java which will validate this date as week day or weekend.

the methods are something like this.

```
public boolean isWeekday(Date dt){

    //process here
    return true;
}
```

and

```
public boolean isWeekend(Date dt){

    //process here
    return true;    
}
```

What should i code to validate the date given?

Thanks..

Comment: flagged to be moved to SO - you also need to tag this with Homework (if that's what it is)

Comment: Is locale important? Saturday is a week day in Japan. Thursday and Friday are the weekend in some muslim countries.

Answer (score 10):

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(dt);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
return day == Calendar.SUNDAY || day == Calendar.SATURDAY;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(dt.getYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDay());
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);    // 6=Friday
```

For weekdays, dayOfWeek equals 2 (Monday), 3 (Tuesday), 4 (Wednesday), 5 (Thursday), 6 (Friday)

For weekends, dayOfWeek equal 7 (Saturday), 1 (Sunday)

Comment: You should use the constants like Calendar.SUNDAY and Calendar.SATURDAY, not the numerical values.